# llvm/clang re-compilation with itself

Tags: c++, clang

After reading many questions on here, I decided to give clang a go, and installed the svn version on Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit). I was expecting issues, but it all compiled smoothly with no warnings.

I noticed though that when re-running the configure script, if clang/clang++ is in your path it will choose this over gcc/g++ for its own compilation. Is it a good idea to recompile llvm/clang with itself? I know this is absolutely standard with gcc, but I've read that clang's C++ implementation isn't quite good enough yet (maybe this is out of date info...).

Comment: Your comment "I was expecting issues, but it all compiled smoothly with no warnings." is a great description of why using clang/llvm over pretty much any of the alternatives is a great idea.

Comment: Ha - well, it's because I'd seen a few questions on here where things wouldn't work on Linux with clang. I'm guessing the latest updates have fixed most of these issues. gcc won't compile on Ubuntu 12.04 without patches, so I'm glad this went better.

Comment: At this point, if things don't compile with clang, it's because they're broken. Breaking the gcc monoculture helps catch new bugs, just like the odd things that turn up when you port an application to a new OS.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I would not go as far as that. Clang works pretty well on linux/Mac, has some issues in windows and does not support any other platform, for starters. The fact that it is able to compile its own code base is not a reason to prefer it over any other compiler either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang has been self hosting for a few years. Losing that ability would be a serious regression.

Clang's current C++ support is quite good. Even much of C++11 is already available for your use.

If you want to be safe, stay on a stable branch.